# Programmatically browse iOS file system from mac

Tags: ios, macos, filesystems

How can I browse an iOS file system (e.g. iPhone) that is connected via USB to a mac?

I know it is possible because some programs are doing it (e.g. [iexplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) or even iTunes itself).

Here are some of the solutions I found:

- Jailbreaking. That is out of the question for me for obvious reasons
- downloading and using third party software like [iexplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). I do not want to do this, because this is closed source software, and I do not know if I can trust it.
- I tried to look into github for open source project that would do something like that, so that I can get inspiration. But I didn't find any project doing something like that.

Comment: You can't explore the raw filesystem without jailbreaking.
You can only access application's private storage

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I access applications' private storage ?

Comment: Have a look at libmobileidevice.

Comment: @gkpln3 if you want to post this as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at libmobileidevice suite: https://github.com/libimobiledevice

Specifically ifuse: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse